# Complex HAProxy Setup with HTTP2 and HTTP1 togather

Tags: haproxy, http2

We have a complex haproxy setup, where one https frontend were used with multiple backend based on path, host name, subdomians, sni, ssl termination etc. Now in one of our case we need to use http2 with all those http backends. and most importantly it should be support host name based routing to different backends. Our backend support both http2 and http1 we just need to forward traffic there after terminating ssl based on hostname.

Couldn't find much more examples related to http2 in Haproxy. All those i found used mode tcp in frontend like this. I am afraid using mode tcp could break my http routings.
So how could i may accomplish this?

Our Haproxy version is 1.7.1
OS Ubuntu16.04

originally asked on [discourse.haproxy.org](http://discourse.haproxy.org/t/complex-haproxy-setup-with-http2-and-http1-togather/925)